# Who were the Jewish Governors during the Persian Era?

Tags: history, ezra-nechemya

Has an approximate line of **Jewish governors** been identified during the period from Cyrus to Alexander? The only names I have are Sheshbazzar, Zerubbabel and Nehemiah.  I am referring to governors - not to high priests. Are any other governors known?

Comment: First of all, why do you assume that such a line exists? Secondly, Zerubavel and Nechemiah were the same person (Sanhedrin 38a). And third, what about the rest of the Anshei Knesses HaHedolah?

Comment: Im not assuming; Im asking.  If you have links to your references please provide them.  Thanks.

Comment: In the first of Argon's links - Bar Kochva's article - there is mention of a governor named Hezekiah that put his name on a series of "Yehud" coins.  The dates of his rule is disputed, as the article mentions, but it makes for interesting reading - they think he was governor right at the end of the Persian Period.

Answer (score 2):

Here are lists from several academic sources:

1. Bar-Kochva's "[Pseudo-Hecataeus on the Jews](http://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft3290051c&chunk.id=d0e12869&toc.depth=1&toc.id=&brand=ucpress)"
2. Kuhurt's "[The Persian Empire: A Corpus of Sources from the Achaemenid Period](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=q3z1Tgb-AG8C&lpg=PA1107&pg=PA1107)"
3. Grabbe's "[A History of the Jews and Judaism in the Second Temple Period](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=1cPeBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA148&pg=PA148) "

It should be emphasized that there is significant uncertainty in the chronologies. Moreover, due to lack of literary and archaeological sources from the time, they are also incomplete.